# Probability by bearing of children

Tags: probability

A married couple agreed to continue bearing a new child until they get two boys, but not more than $5$ children. Assuming that each time that a child is born the probability that it is a boy is $0.5$ independent from all other times, find the probability that the couple has at least two girls.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you, say, enumerate the cases where the couple winds up with fewer than two girls?

Comment: I have tried looking for the possible combinations for example : GGGGG,GGGBB,GGBGB,BGGGB,GGBB,BGBGG,I don't when to stop and what to do next.

Comment: Well, in some cases (like this one) it is easier to look for the opposite of what you want.  "fewer than two" just means "$0$ or $1$".  So...list the cases where there are $0$ girls (very easy).  Then list the cases where there is exactly $1$ (still pretty easy).

Comment: Note:  your last case ($BGBGG$) is not possible.  They would have stopped after $BGB$. (I assume you are reading from left to right.  If you are reading from right to left then the cases $GGGBB$, $GGBB$ are impossible).

Comment: @lulu For 0-**BB**,For 1- **GBB**,**BGB**,For 2-**GGBB**,**GBGB**,**BGGB**,For 3-**BGGGB**,**GBGGB**,**GGBGB**,**GGGBB**,For 4-**BGGGG**,**GBGGG**,**GGBGG**,**GGGBG**,**GGGGB**,For 5-**GGGGG**

Comment: @lulu Am I missing anything?If not ,what do I do next?

Comment: Great!  Now, the cases "at least $2$" and "fewer than $2$" are mutually exclusive and exhaustive.  That means their probabilities add to $1$. You've correctly listed the scenarios giving fewer than $2$, can you add up their probabilities?  (actually, given your full list you could do this on the other scenarios but it is harder to be sure you've listed all the cases.)  You could do it as a check!

Comment: @lulu what do you mean?

Comment: Each of the scenarios you listed has a probability.  Can you work out all of them?  (hint:  it isn't hard).

Comment: @lulu For 0- (1/2)(1/2)=1/4 chance, For 1-(1/2)(1/2)(1/2)=1/8 chance for every scenario to happen when there is at least one girl,For 2-(1/2)(1/2)(1/2)(1/2)=1/16 chance for every scenario,For 3,4 and 5 (1/2)(1/2)(1/2)(1/2)(1/2)=1/32 chance for every scenario.is this right?

Comment: Perfect.  Can you solve the problem now?

Comment: No,I don't know what to do with those values.

Comment: Ok.  Well, the probability of disjoint events is additive.  Thus, the probability that our couple will have exactly one girl is, by your analysis, $\frac 18+\frac 18 =\frac 14$.  Can you do the parallel computation for each of your cases?  (Note:  as a check, your values should add up to $1$ as we know that exactly one of these events will happen).

Comment: @lulu two- 3/16 ,Three- 4/32=1/8,four- 5/32,five- 1/32.           Do I add all of them?

Comment: Yes.  And as a check, make sure that all 5 scenarios add to $1$.

Comment: Note:  once you have got the answer and done the check, you might want to write it up and post it as a solution.  It's good practice to write things out carefully, especially when (as here) there are lots of cases to consider and it's good to have a complete solution to questions posted on this site.

Comment: @lulu oh okay.thank you!

Comment: @lulu I got a 36/32,did I do anything wrong?

Comment: I think so...let's see.  Your probabilities are $\{\frac 14,\frac 14,\frac 3{16},\frac 4{32},\frac 5{32},\frac 1{32}\}$ , right?  So if we use $32$ as a common denominator we get $\{\frac 8{32},\frac 8{32},\frac 6{32},\frac 4{32},\frac 5{32},\frac 1{32}\}$.  Adding we get $\frac {8+8+6+4+5+1}{32}=\frac {32}{32}=1\}$.  Looks good to me!

Comment: We shouldn't forget child is born the probability that it is a boy is $0.5$. It's very important. the probability that one case happen is different from other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If the couple have *less than* $2$ girls then they must have stopped after $2$ boys.

Possible scenarios: $BB$, $BGB$ and $GBB$.

Having at least $2$ girls is the complement of this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the probability of the couple having less than 2 girls. The probable cases are: $BGB, GBB, BB$, where B,G stands for boy and girl respectively. Thus the probability in this case is $P'=(1/2)^3+(1/2)^3 +(1/2)^2=0.5$

Therefore the required probability is $P= 1-P'=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the stopping-after-five-children part is unnecessary information. If the couple has at least four children then they definitely have at least two girls, because it is given that they will never have more than two boys.

The cases for two girls are:

- First two children are GG
- First three children are GBG
- First three children are BGG

You can enumerate several subcases if you like, showing exactly what kind of children the couple had in sequence in each case (there will always be at least four children in the end, sometimes five), but it is not necessary.

The complementary cases are the ones where the couple has fewer than two girls. This can only happen if they have two boys, as follows:

- First two children are BB
- First two children are BGB
- First two children are GBB

Each of these cases shows exactly what children the couple has, since they stop after two boys. All six cases (the three for two or more girls, and the three for fewer girls) are disjoint, so the probability of their union is the 
sum of their probabilities.
You can confirm that the six probabilities add up to $1$, which shows that
no cases are missing from the analysis.

It may be helpful to enumerate the case by drawing a probability tree,
as I have done (somewhat clumsily) below, starting with no children.
You do not have to complete the probability tree; you only need to follow
each branch far enough so that either the condition "at least two girls"
is satisfied or the couple stops having children because they had at least two boys. It should be clear that at least one of these conditions will be
satisfied by the time there are three children.
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
&&&& 0 & \\
&&&\swarrow & & \searrow \\
&& G &&&& B \\
&\swarrow &  \downarrow &&&& \downarrow & \searrow \\
GG && GB &&&& BG && BB \\
&\swarrow &  \downarrow &&&& \downarrow & \searrow \\
GBG && GBB &&&& BGG && BGB
\\
\end{array}